# Programm with "read/write into .txt-file" -> Export to .jar -> Common implementation?

Tags: java, file-io, jar

I have a programm in which i read and write from/to a .txt file.
My plan was, that i create a "res" folder which contains the .txt file. The "res" folder is added to the buildpath and if i export this project to a .jar file, if have only one .jar file with the .txt file included.

But now i know, that it is not possible to write into a .jar file.

My actually plan is now, that i don't add the "res"-folder to the build path, export the projekt as .jar file, put the .jar file in a "my programm" folder and put the "res" folder into the "my programm" folder too. Then it should work, but i find this solution dirty...

Is that the common way to do this?
My favorite was the "only one .jar file with all included" but that's not working....

For a alternative:
I heard in the past that it exists a "integreated database" for java. If i use such a integreated database instead of my .txt file, can in use in that case my favorite solution "only one .jar file with all included"?

Comment: Writable files should not be located in the same folder as your program. Either let the user choose where he would like to save things (just like your preferred text editor), or write to a specific file in a specific sub-directory of the user's home directory (in `HOME/.yourProgram/preferences.txt` for example)

Comment: Java applications certainly can write into a jar file. Just not their _own_ jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what sort of data you are storing in the .txt file, you may wish to consider the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/), which is a standard way to store configuration information that you need to persist from one run of your program to the next.  This is a cross-platform API that stores data in an appropriate way for whatever platform you're running on - in the registry on Windows, in `.plist` files under `~/Library` on Mac, and in hidden files in the user's home directory on Linux (but you don't need to care about the back-end, the API is the same in all cases).

Answer (score 1):

Do you only need to save the state of your application to load it on start? Just save your state into a file in a user's home directory, for example, or any other suitable place on file system. You can also use embedded database, but it'll also be a file on the disk in the end.

Comment: In my .txt file i write and read a List-Object, which is constantly chaning his content.

Comment: You mean, you serialize Objects to file? Then maybe, depending on your structure, it's worth to consider using an embedded database. Anyway, it's not about representation, but the application design. It is not wise to try to bundle application state in a jar, even if it's possible. De facto standard is an application should store their settings and resources in corresponding storage. You don't want to end up to distribute previously saved password of a user, for example, when application jar is copied to another user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

> I heard in the past that it exists a "integreated database" for java.

The integrated database is [JavaDB.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) It is included in the JDK.

> If i use such a integreated database instead of my .txt file, can in use in that case my favorite solution "only one .jar file with all included"?

Any extra writeable files needed by your application - such as, in this case, the file storing the data in the JavaDB database - can be stored initially in the jar and then copied onto an appropriate place on the disk. You could also make a separate installer application to do that - that's the standard approach for Windows applications.